Understanding amplifier sub-circuit

I don't really grasp, what should be the purpose of this circuit above. It provides an output after the diode D109 that is also combined with the output of another circuit coming through the diode D116 (not depicted here). This other circuit is a MUTE signal coming from an auto-off circuit that mutes the amplifier after a giving time without input signal. However I don't get what could be the function of this circuit of the picture. It seems it is comparing 0.6V (on the - input of the opamp) with some other voltage on the + input that can be adjusted through the potentiometer R138. But that would lead to either having a +15V or -15V on the output of the opamp (given that the supply is -15/+15V).
But first of all i can't really imagine why such a circuit would be combined with the MUTE signal anyways and secondly, there are easier manners to provide -15V or +15V than this, so I assume that could have something to do with power supply stability...? Like compensating the +15V level perhaps?
Any hints are appreciated.
EDIT
The circuit above refers to the schematics of the JBL SCS 138/178 active Subwoofer circuit (amplifier).
EDIT2
There are multiple third-party websites that provide the schematics of this circuit so here is one of them, where the complete circuit can be found:
Full schematics
and here are the real fotos of the circuit:



and in the last picture i suspect the green circle is the Q115 and the red circle is definitely the Q116. So it does make sense that it has something to do with temperature. I just dont really follow how that could act as a temperature sensor... when Q115 becomes hotter than it changes its voltage drop and therefore can change the opamp comparison, resulting in the muting of the whole circuit to cool down the circuit a little bit? And the potentiometer is just a fine adjustment of this temperature threshold?

It could be over-temperature protection circuit. Where Q115 act as a temperature sensor if Q115 is mounted on the heatsink. And U101 as a comparator with hysteresis.

Please show a picture of this circuit in the subwoofer. It's important to see what it is mechanically connected to. The schematic may not show the whole picture. E.g. some components of the circuit may be thermally bound to other components.

I concur with @G36.  Do you know if Q115 is mounted on the heatsink with the power output drivers?
